# Does VSCode support git-repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repo

I have a project that uses [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/) so it contains multiple repos. The only way I can find of supporting this in VSCode is to use [multi-root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) and add each repo as a separate folder within the workspace.

Is there any support or extension for git-repo (or any planned) so I could just open the root folder where the .repo directory is and have VSCode recognise this automatically?

Comment: I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93697

Comment: Please upvote so it gets on the backlog!